# NextJs Cache on Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, caching, next.js, server-side-rendering

We have a large NextJs project that works with server-side-rendering as it generates routes dynamically. It is dockerized and running on Kubernetes with autoscaling, so depending on the amount of traffic the amount of replicas varies from 3 to 10.
Every time a new replica is created (by autoscale or by a new deployment), it does not contain inside the cache of the pages or images, so we experience two problems, the rendering times can be more than 10 seconds, and the other problem is the excessive consumption of pod resources (0.8 cpu, 800 mb memory) during the generation of the cache.

We use usually two fetch methods. getStaticProps and getServerSideProps.
The issue only appears on getServerSideProps and the first render of getStaticProps as we don't use pre-cache with getStaticPaths

Is there any way to store that cache in a PV + PVC? Or has anyone found an effective way to mitigate these two problems?

Stack:

- Next 13.0.4
- Docker imageBase node:16.14-alpine3.15
- Google Cloud Platform - GKE
- Instance Type: e2-standard-4 (4 CPU, 16 GB Ram)

We increased the resources allocated to the container in the Pod and tested with n2-standard-4 instances, which resulted in a minimal decrease in cache generation time, but not a difference that we are satisfied with.

Comment: Have you found a solution ?